# How to follow url using jinja in django?

Tags: python, django, jinja2

```
urlpattern = [
path('', views.foo, name='foo')
path('hello/', views.hello, name='hello')
]
```

`<a href="{% url 'myapp:hello' %}">Link</a>` .....this will follow the second path

WHAT FOR FIRST PATH?
`<a href="{% url 'myapp:' %}">Link</a>` ....not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documentation regarding template tag [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url) states

```
 <a href="{% url 'myapp:foo' %}">Link</a>
```